# I am getting 'The resource could not be found.' error in salesforce using Microsoft q365

Tags: salesforce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yplAZ.png)
Sometime i am getting 'The resource could not be found.' error in salesforce when i am clicking on channel tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPq03.png)

'The resource could not be found' due to this error i am not able to upload file in my teams channel.